# can't access the self of another class

Tags: objective-c

I have a class that is all about XML requests.  In one method (`xmlRequest`), I call another function in `Request` (`returnXML`) and pass it a `DDXMLDocument`.  The point of `returnXML` is to set the `xmlDocument` as a property of self so I can access it in different files, mainly the ViewController.  I can print out `self->xmlDocument` in the `returnXML` but when i try to print it out in the ViewController, it says `NULL`.  Am I doing something wrong?

In Request.m:

```
-(void)returnXML: (DDXMLDocument *) xmldoc
 {
    self->xmlDocument =xmldoc;
    NSLog(@"%@", [self->xmlDocument XMLStringWithOptions:DDXMLNodePrettyPrint]); //prints doc
    return xmldoc; 
 }
```

In ViewController:

```
Request *http=[[Request alloc] init];
[http xmlRequest:@"http://legalindexes.indoff.com/sitemap.xml"];
NSLog(@"%@",[http->xmlDocument XMLStringWithOptions:DDXMLNodePrettyPrint]); //prints doc
```

this is where I call returnXML

```
 -(void)xmlRequest:(NSString *)xmlurl
{
    AFKissXMLRequestOperation* operation= [AFKissXMLRequestOperation XMLDocumentRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:xmlurl]] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
       // self.XMLDocument=XMLDocument;
        [self returnXML:XMLDocument];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
        NSLog(@"Failure!");
    }];
    [operation start];
```

Comment: -(void)returnXML: (DDXMLDocument *) xmldoc , why is void with a return?

Answer (score 1):

You are not retaining `xmldoc` so it is being released.

You need to create a `@property` and `@synthesize` the getter and setter methods:

In Request.h:

```
@interface Request : NSObject
{
   DDXMLDocument *_xmlDocument;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic, readwrite) DDXMLDocument *xmlDocument;

...

@end
```

in Request.m:

```
@implementation Request

@synthesize xmlDocument = _xmlDocument;

-(void)returnXML: (DDXMLDocument *) xmldoc
{
    self.xmlDocument = xmldoc;    // Use the setter!
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.xmlDocument XMLStringWithOptions:DDXMLNodePrettyPrint]);
    // No return from void!!!
}

@end
```

In ViewController:

```
Request *http=[[Request alloc] init];
[http xmlRequest:@"http://legalindexes.indoff.com/sitemap.xml"];
NSLog(@"%@",[http.xmlDocument XMLStringWithOptions:DDXMLNodePrettyPrint]);
```

However I cannot workout what your `returnXML` method is supposed to return if it's defined as `void`.  I'll leave that to you to work out.

Comment: thank you, I changed all that but it still says null when I try to 

NSLog(@"%@",[http.document XMLStringWithOptions:DDXMLNodePrettyPrint]);

Comment: @Becksters And is `returnXML` being called to assign `xmldoc`?  If so where?  (you might have to post more code).

Comment: returnXML is being passed xmldoc from xmlRequest, I edited my question and posted some more code

Comment: @Becksters And what if you forget about `returnXML` (as it does nothing) and uncomment the `self.XMLDocument=XMLDocument` call?

Comment: ahhh I figured it out... I can just return in my xmlRequest as long as it's outside the success block